# Maven: obtain path to output JAR from integration test

Tags: java, maven

I want to write an E2E test for a Maven project. The flow would be to run the resulting JAR and verify it's output. The question is how can I obtain the path to the output JAR from an integration test (written in JUnit run by the Failsafe plugin).

Answer (score 0):

You can either use command line or make an entry in pom.xml to tell where you want jar file saved.

on command line

```
-DoutputDirectory=<specify_your_path>
```

On in your pom.xml

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>x.y.z</version>
      <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>/your/path/for/jar</outputDirectory>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

**Now on how to read path in test** : The unit test will still run even if not using Maven, the target directory will still get created two dirs up relative to the current working directory of wherever the tests are run. You can use the method below to get the target directory in test.

```
public File targetDir(){
  String relPath = getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getFile();
  File targetDir = new File(relPath+"../../target");
  if(!targetDir.exists()) {
    targetDir.mkdir();
  }
  return targetDir;
}
```